# SQLite order by decimal numbers?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, select, join

I have an SQLite DB where I would do a table join and order by a field `orderID`.  I needed to insert a new orderID between two existing ones (6 and 7), and a MYSQL person recommended just using 6.5 as this item's orderID.  However, when I use the following SQL that row is not even selected:

```
select i.caption, i_s.orderID, i_s.sectionID, i_s.name, r.fcid, r.pdf, r.title 
from recipes r 
inner join instructions i on r.fcid = i.recipeID 
inner join inst_sections i_s on i.timeID = i_s.sectionID 
where fcid IN (114806) 
order by i_s.orderID ASC
```

I get all the other orderIDs, in order, as expected but the 6.5 one is not in the selection set.  What am I missing here?

Comment: Looks like that field was an INT field.  It also looks like SQLite doesn't support MODIFY. So I guess I am stuck.

Comment: SQLite should happily store a floating point value in a field declared INT (it's very loosely typed), so make sure 1) that you really INSERTed or UPDATEd to the floating point value and 2) that recipe 114806 really has the section with orderid 6.5 included.

Comment: Thank you Larry, I wasn't aware. It works now.